# ViewModel Data Loses State When Accessed From Second Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm facing an issue with my ViewModel that I use to hold user login data.

I update this ViewModel with user data from fragment A after a user logs in, but when I try to access the data from fragment B the data fields I just set are always null.

When fragment B is initialized the `user` LiveData field is never initially observed, however, when I trigger a change to the `user` object from fragment B the change is correctly observed within fragment B. It appears that the previous values of the fields in my ViewModel never reach fragment B, but new values do.

For a sanity check I made a simple string variable (not even a LiveData object) that I set to a value from fragment A, then, after navigating to fragment B I printed the value: it is uninitialized every time. It's as if the ViewModel I inject into fragment B is totally separate from the ViewModel I inject into fragment A.

What am I missing that causes the ViewModel observation in fragment B not to initially trigger with the last known value of `user` set from fragment A?

Fragment A

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.user.observe(this, {
            it?.let {
                //Called successfully every time
                navigateToFragmentB()
            }
        })
        
        val mockUserData = User()
        viewModel.loginSuccess(mockUserData)
    }
}
```

Fragment B

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModel()
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        ...
        
        viewModel.user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { user ->
            user?.let {
                binding.initialsBubble.text = user.getInitials()
            } ?: navigateAway()
        })
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel(
    private val loginRepo: LoginRepo
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User?>()
    val user: LiveData<User?> = _user
    

    fun loginSuccess(result: AuthenticationResult) {
        val user = loginRepo.login(result)
        _user.postValue(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Each Fragment gets its own set of ViewModels; FragmentA's ViewModels aren't available in FragmentB. Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)?

Comment: When using same ViewModel for multiple Fragments, you should instantiate each ViewModel using the host activity's context. This works only if all fragments in question are hosted by same activity, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [sharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) for both fragment.

Use these lines of code in both fragments

```
private val viewModel: LoginViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

instead of

```
private val viewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModel()
```

Comment: Hi! So i have a problem with this, I have a splash screen and there i get my data and set it to my viewmodel, but on the next screen the current state is null. I am using activityViewModels(). What may be the issue here?